# Measuring regression coefficients contribution using anova

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I wanted to ask about anova F-test. Can this test be used to measure coefficients contribution on dependent variable?

Anova test compares variations between and within a certain groups and in linear regression we use it to test wheater all regression coefficiets (apart from intercept) are equal to zero.

My question is if we can compare sum square of  residuals for each term used in regression as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)


mtcars %>% 
  lm(hp ~ factor(gear) + factor(am) + qsec + wt, data = .) %>% 
  aov() %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
  mutate(contribution = sumsq/sum(sumsq))
```

Can we intepret this summary output as: *gear* explains about 44 percents of variability in dependent variable? That *qsec* explains about 25% of variablitity? Can this approach be used in practice as e.g. If we have to choose ONLY one variable for explaining dependent variable we should choose *gear* in this example with only this variables?

I would like to ask if this is correct or not and most importantly why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your interpretation is correct. One way to see this is that if we take the sum of all `sumsq`, substract the `sumsq` of the Residuals and divide this quantity by the sum of `sumsq`, we get the R-squared of the regression (so the % of total variance explained by our model).

```
mtcars %>% 
  lm(hp ~ factor(gear) + factor(am) + qsec + wt, data = .) %>% 
  aov() %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
  mutate(contribution = sumsq/sum(sumsq),
         r_squared = (sum(sumsq) - sumsq[term == "Residuals"]) / sum(sumsq))

# A tibble: 5 x 8
  term            df  sumsq meansq statistic       p.value contribution r_squared
  <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
1 factor(gear)     2 64213. 32106.    33.3    0.0000000680      0.441       0.828
2 factor(am)       1   759.   759.     0.787  0.383             0.00521     0.828
3 qsec             1 36567. 36567.    37.9    0.00000165        0.251       0.828
4 wt               1 19098. 19098.    19.8    0.000144          0.131       0.828
5 Residuals       26 25090.   965.    NA     NA                 0.172       0.828

mtcars %>% 
  lm(hp ~ factor(gear) + factor(am) + qsec + wt, data = .) %>% 
  summary() %>% .["r.squared"]
$r.squared
[1] 0.8278279
```

The proportion of variance explained by one main effect (or interaction effect) is called "eta squared" and is an [effect size](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/effect-size/#:~:text=Like%20the%20R%20Squared%20statistic,attributed%20to%20a%20specific%20X.) measure. There are functions to compute this, for example with the `lsr` package:

```
aov_model <- aov(hp ~ (gear) + (am) + qsec + wt, data = mtcars) 
library(lsr)
etaSquared(aov_model, type = 1)

          eta.sq eta.sq.part
gear 0.440638981   0.7190454
am   0.005210947   0.0293768
qsec 0.250925660   0.5930678
wt   0.131052319   0.4321958
```

You could use this in practice to select the most important variables, but I would choose other models like lasso regression to do that.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Can you please also show how to calculate *sumsq* by hand in R for each term?

Comment: I will just link to this (http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/anova_of_OLS_models.html) if this is ok?